# Qsort removes first element from array (char *)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, quicksort

I am very new to C and I am trying to use qsort() with an array of char pointers. It is not sorting the array alphabetically as I expected and it removes the first element. I have tried adjusting all of the arguments including the comparison function but I have been unable to figure out what is wrong.

Enter word: foo
Enter word: bar
Enter word: baz
Enter word: quux

**Expected:**
bar
baz
foo
quux

**Result:**

bar
baz
quux

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 10
#define MAX_LENGTH 20

int read_line(char str[], int n);
int compare(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void) {
  char *words[MAX_WORDS], word[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
    printf("Enter word: ");
    read_line(word, MAX_LENGTH);

    words[i] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    if(!words[i]) {
      printf("Allocation of memory failed...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(words[i], word);

    if(!strlen(words[i]))
      break;
  }

  qsort(words[0], i, sizeof(char *), compare);

  for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[j]);
  }

  return 0;
}

int read_line(char str[], int n) {
  int ch, i;

  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if(i < n)
      str[i++] = ch;
  }
  str[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return strcmp((char *) a, (char *) b);
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT edit the question to fix the problems that were the reason to write the question in first place. This makes the whole question and all answers worthless as no one can see the problem without looking into edit history. A question should not be a moving target.

Comment: @Gerhardh Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three errors.

1. `qsort` requires a pointer to the first element of the array being sorted.

   Replace

   ```
   qsort(words[0], i, sizeof(char *), compare);
   ```

   with

   ```
   qsort(&( words[0] ), i, sizeof(char *), compare);
   ```

   or just

   ```
   qsort(words, i, sizeof(char *), compare);
   ```

   This latter version works because an array used where a pointer is expected decays into a pointer to its first element.
2. The compare function is passed pointers to the elements of the array being sorted. Since you are sorting an array of pointers, that means the compare function is passed pointers to those pointers (`char**`) in your case. As such, `compare` should be

   ```
   static int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
     return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
   }
   ```

   Even better:

   ```
   static int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
     return strcmp(*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);
   }
   ```
3. Your final loop has one too many passes.

   If `i<MAX_WORDS` (because a blank line was entered), this will cause a blank line to be emitted (because `words[i]` contains a zero-length string). If `i==MAX_WORDS`, this invokes *Undefined Behaviour* (because `words[i]` is beyond the end of the array).

   Replace

   ```
   for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
   ```

   with

   ```
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing (just) the first string to qsort, not the address of the array.  You need

```
 qsort(words, i, sizeof(char *), compare);
```

Once you fix that, you'll find that your compare routine is incorrect, as it is called with the adresses of the elements of the words array, not the values in it.  So you need

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(char **) a, *(char **) b);
}
```

to actually fetch the char *'s from the array and compare the strings.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I'm a bit confused as to why I need to do *(char **). Where is (char **) a pointing to?

Comment: @Eric Leus, That and other things are explained in my answer. It also identifies a third problem this answer missed.